# How do I get READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE runtime permission to work for my app in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

I am trying to add in code to ask for permission in runtime to user for read_external_storage, I used in the past dexter implementation in my build gradle file and added the code in my MainActivity.java but this doesn't work anymore. Does anyone know what the current and most up to date method for asking for runtime permission for read_external_storage in android studio for sdks between 21 to 32?

Comment: All works as before. The only thing is that you should not ask this permission at runtime for Android 13 devices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the permission beforehand in the android manifest file with the `<uses-permission>` and maybe `<uses-feature>` if you need to access external storage.

Also, Android have moved to Kotlin and Jetpack / Jetpack Compose. Legacy code will work... but things are quite different now. Specially with permissions. You don't request them anymore. You announce them in the Android Manifest file. Also, Android limits the maximum Android Version that is *allowed* to write to external storage. So the Manifest file needs to call a tool:

```
<uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
  tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way would be to have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in the manifest file. Sometimes you need,

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

also in the manifest file.

Also,

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

in the java file.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

> Note: Starting in API level 33, this permission has no effect. If your app accesses other apps' media files, request one or more of these permissions instead: READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, READ_MEDIA_AUDIO. Learn more about the [storage permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#storage-permission) that are associated with media files.

```xml
<!-- Required only if your app needs to access images or photos
     that other apps created. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />

<!-- Required only if your app needs to access videos
     that other apps created. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

<!-- Required only if your app needs to access audio files
     that other apps created. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To ask for the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to the user, first you need to add the permission in your manifest file like below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then in your `Activity.java` file, you need to add the following code:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Create a request code
    public static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        //Check if permission has been granted
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            //Your code
        }
        //Otherwise request permission 
        else {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } 
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermissions() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity.this, new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
}
```

You also need to add the following import:

```
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
```

Comment: the code for Activity.java has multiple problem, onRequestPermissionsResult has an error its reccommended to have a super call, grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;) is not a statement and "else" has no "if"

Comment: @Marfog509 I have edited my answer. Pls check. However, there isn't any `else` statement without an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this snippet to include the external storage permission

```
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU){
        arrayOf(
           Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
           Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO,
           Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO
        ) 
      }
      else {
        arrayOf(
         Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
         Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
      }
```

This will be safe when it comes to the new android API.

Comment: I only need permission to read pdf files. What is the specific code for this in MainActivity.java?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
` This will be permission to access the files in your android device

Answer (score 0):

Step1: add permission on android manifest.xml:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Step2: check for a permission and to request a permission from the user when necessary:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// Should we show an explanation?
if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
 
}

requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

return;
```

}

Step3: Callback

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull final String[] permissions, @NonNull final int[] grantResults) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION) {
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission granted.
    } else {
        //  Permission Refused.
    }
}
}
```