# What is the best way to modify a text file under /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/another.installed.package/files/ using SAF in Android 12?

Tags: java, android

I need change one text file in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/another.installed.package/files/text.txt`
Under Android 12 there is a error `Access denied`.
Need java code for do the thing, probably, using SAF

Already get this https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager, and it works somehow, and gives me access to desired file
also checked very highscored answer [How do some apps reach the contents of ".../Android/..." sub-folders on Android 11 without root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65967690/how-do-some-apps-reach-the-contents-of-android-sub-folders-on-android/66466205),

but nothing, can't get it

also added `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

Oh God, on Android 10 works without any troubles

Comment: Check my answer on this link. That might solve your problem.https://stackoverflow.com/a/76259315/5362509

Comment: If you want to use SAF then permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is useless.

Comment: So just use SAF for it.

Comment: i tried SAF, why it is over complicated? I appreciate any working Java-code.

Comment: Or at least a method for reading a text file from a third-party package. And then I'll figure it out myself.

Comment: What do you consider to be over complicated? And SAF is available in Java too. Once you obtained the uri for the file using saf the rest is about the same as using a classic file path.