Error: ENOENT: /data/user/0/com.notaedeo/databases/dbnotas.db: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied), open "path", in android 10(api 29)
in my app made in react native happen this error:
Error: ENOENT: /data/user/0/com.notaedeo/databases/dbnotas.db: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied), open "path"

This error happen after i copy some files by the app that is being made
I search for the solution and nothing working
and this my androidmanifest.xml:
 <manifest>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:maxSdkVersion="28"
/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
android:maxSdkVersion="28"
/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
    ...
<application 
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true" 
... >
        ...
        <activity> 
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest> 


In the permissions  declared in your manifest you specified that the max sdk version is 28 for all of the permissions so api 29 and more wont be affected by that so try to increase the max sdk version or see if higher api’s require a different permission if that didn’t work.

I did this and it doesn't work

As i understood this error only appears in the api 29 not the lower ones isn’t it?
And also make sure that you ask the user for the permission explicitly at the run time

Take a look at this this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76258370/how-do-i-get-read-external-storage-runtime-permission-to-work-for-my-app-in-andr

Man, actually in the past there was no problem when i build my app with this androidmanifest.xml but now after back to programming(i stoped the develop for a time) and update the react native(i created another project and i copied the old code), and did not work.
